# Writing basic proofs about cycles?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

These are extremely straightforward statements, but I'm getting flustered by how someone would go about constructing proofs to solve these...

(a) Every cycle is connected

(b) Every cycle is 2-regular

(c) Conversely, every connected, 2-regular graph must be a cycle.

The logic behind these is very straightforward, but constructing a proof is giving me difficulty. If I could get any help, it would be appreciated!

Comment: To me, a) and b) hold by definition.  But it all depends on the definition you have.  Can you define a cycle formally ?

Answer (score 1):

The first two are really just a matter of having a clear definition of a cycle and working with it.

I define an $n$-cycle to be a graph with vertices $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ and edges $\{v_k,v_{k\oplus 1}\}$ for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$, where for $r,s\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ we define $k\oplus\ell=(k+\ell)\bmod n$. Similarly, we define $k\ominus\ell=(k-\ell)\bmod n$. (This is just a clever trick to avoid having to treat the edge $\{v_{n-1},v_0\}$ as a special case.) Let $C$ be an $n$-cycle.

- If $k,\ell\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, there is a unique $r\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $\ell=k\oplus r$. Then the sequence $\langle v_k,v_{k\oplus 1},\ldots,v_{k\oplus r}\rangle$ is a path in $C$ from $v_k$ to $v_\ell$, so $C$ is connected.
- For any $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, the vertices of $C$ connected to $v_k$ by edges are $v_{k\ominus 1}$ and $v_{k\oplus 1}$, so $C$ is $2$-regular.

It’s the third one that requires more than just working directly with the definition of a cycle. Suppose that $G$ is $2$-regular and has $n$ vertices. Let $v_0$ be any vertex of $G$, and let $v_1$ be one of the two vertices adjacent to $v_0$. Since $\deg v_1=2$, there must be some vertex $v_2\ne v_0$ adjacent to $v_1$. In general, given adjacent vertices $v_{k-1}$ and $v_k$, let $v_{k+1}$ be the unique vertex adjacent to $v_k$ and different from $v_{k-1}$. Since $G$ has only $n$ vertices, for some smallest $k\le n-1$ we must have $v_{k+1}=v_\ell$ for some $\ell\in\{0,\ldots,k-2\}$.

- Show that $\ell$ must be $0$.
- Conclude that the subgraph of $G$ induced by $\{v_0,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a $(k+1)$-cycle and a component of $G$.
- Conclude further that if $G$ is connected, then $k+1=n$, and this cycle is all of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that we know the fact that for graph $G$ with minimum degree $\delta(G)\geq 2$, it must contain some cycle $C$. Now, suppose there is vertex $v\in V(G)\setminus V(C)$, then $v$ must be disconneced from $C$, otherwise some vertex in $V(C)$ must have degree at least 3. With $V(G)=V(C)$ and the $2$-regularity, we conclude that $G=C$, as all edges must be in $E(C)$.